# How to filters array of object by array of object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem to filters data inside the array of objects by an array of objects. I already try using filters combine with the includes method but returning an empty array.

let's say I have array an array called listOfPermissions.

```
listOfPermissions = [
        {name:'A',IsChecked:true},
        {name:'B',IsChecked:true},
        {name:'C',IsChecked:true}
]
```

Than i want to filter the list with permissionOnRole array

```
permissionOnRole = [
        {name:'C',IsChecked: true}    
]
```

The goals i want to achieve

```
result = [
    {name:'A',IsChecked:true},
    {name:'B',IsChecked:true},
]
```

this is my code

```
const setUncheckPermissions = () => {
    const permissionsOnRole = role.permissions.map(it => ({name: it, isChecked: true}))
    const listOfAllPermissions = props.permissions.map((permission) => {return {name: permission['name'], isChecked: true}});


    let result = listOfAllPermissions.filter(item => permissionsOnRole.includes(item));

    console.log(listOfAllPermissions)

}
```

please help me to solve this problems
**Thank you in advance**

Comment: `includes` won't work, because objects are compared by reference, not by nested fields

Answer (score 1):

Just use `filter`

```js
const listOfPermissions = [
        {name:'A',IsChecked:true},
        {name:'B',IsChecked:true},
        {name:'C',IsChecked:true}
]
const permissionOnRole = [
        {name:'C',IsChecked: true}    
]

const result = listOfPermissions.filter(item => !!permissionOnRole.find(i => i.name !== item.name))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: this work , thank you , but im still confuse why my code not working , maybe because of includes?

Comment: yeah. Since your array is a object array. include doesn't work. it works for number or string array